# Discrepancy measures for transition matrices

Tags: estimation, markov-process, distance-functions

I'm doing some work on modelling transition matrices, and for this I need a measure of discrepancy or lack of fit: that is, if I have a matrix $T$ and a target matrix $T_0$, I want to be able to calculate how far $T$ is from $T_0$. Would anyone be able to provide pointers on what measure I should be using?

I've seen some references to using an elementwise squared-error measure, ie sum up the squared differences of the elements of $T$ and $T_0$, but this seems rather ad-hoc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your matrix represent conditional probability I think that using a general matrix norm is a bit artificial. Using some sort of geodesic distance on the set of transition matrix might be more relevant but I clearly prefer to come back to probabilities.

I assume you want to compare $Q=(Q_{ij})$ and $P=(P_{ij})$ with $P_{ij}=P(X^P_{t}=j|X^P_{t-1}=j)$ and that for $P$ (resp. $Q$) there exists a unique stationnary measure $\pi_{P}$ (resp. $\pi_{Q}$).

Under these assumptions, I guess it is meaningfull to compare $\pi_{P}$ and $\pi_{Q}$ for example with a $L_{1}$ distance: $\sum_{j}|\pi_{P}[j]-\pi_{Q}[j]|$ or hellinger distance: $\sum_{j}|\pi^{1/2}_{P}[j]-\pi^{1/2}_{Q}[j]|^2$ or Kullback divergence: $\sum_{j}\pi_{P}[j] \log(\frac{\pi_{P}[j]}{\pi_{Q}[j]})$.

Comment: +1, good idea to relate matrix to measure. This seems very appropriate for OP concern about using matrix norm.

Answer (score 5):

Why does one want the measure of discrepancy to be a true metric? There is a huge literature on axiomatic characterizations of I-divergence as measure of distance. It is neither symmetric nor satisfies triangle inequality.

I hope by 'transition matrix' you mean 'probability transition matrix'. Never mind, as long as the entries are non negative, I-divergence is considered to be the "best" measure of discrimination. See for example http://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/10/3/261/. In fact certain axioms which any one would feel desirable lead to measures which are nonsymmetric in general.

Comment: @Ashok +1 for mentioning alternative measures of discrepancy. On the other hand the I did not find ready available formula to use on matrices in the link you gave. Also it does not say why I-divergence is the "best" measure of discrepancy. Could you please elaborate more on these points?

Comment: You can think of a matrix of order $m\times n$  as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$  as done in matrix norm(the link given by charles.y.zheng) and use the formula $D(A\|B)=\sum(a_i \log \frac{a_i}{b_i}−a_i+b_i)$. For your second question as I already said there's huge literature on why I-divergence is the "best" measure of discrepancy. See for example Csiszar's Annals of Statistics paper "Why least Squares and Maximum Entropy": An axiomatic approach to inference for linear inverse problems. The one which I already mentioned is actually a review of this paper.

Comment: @Ashok, not all matrix norms treat matrices as elements of $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$. Hence ignoring matrix structure by embedding into other space might not be appropriate. Furthermore I suspect OP might not be familiar with this trick, that is why I asked you to elaborate. Your answer is fine, but it cannot be readily used. If you look around the site, the tendency is to give self-contained answers as much as that is possible. I am sorry if you found my comment offensive.

Comment: @Ashok, I looked at the article again, it gives overview of discrepancy measures, but not which one is the "best", or what "best" means. From your answer one can get impression (I for one got it) that the article is about pointing out the "best" discrepancy measure, when in fact it is a survey of discrepancy measures. Sorry for nitpicking.

Comment: I'm not saying this is the best. It's not a new subject that which measure is "good" and which is "bad". It has a huge extensive literature starting from Gibbs-Boltzman-E T Jaynes. They put some axioms which they think "common sense" and show that those common senses leed to this measure of discrimination. So based on whether our model is built on those common senses, we can decide on which measure to deal with.

Comment: @robin: But there's no guarantee for the existence of the stationary probability vectors, right? I don't know why I am not able to comment below your post.

Comment: @Ashok, sorry for nitpicking again. Although you do not claim that particular measure is the best, your answer implies that it is. Your answer provides valuable insight, but I think it might be improved.

Comment: @Ashok, commenting everywhere requires 50 reputation points. Do not worry, I think you will reach them soon.